# Unable to update image in Django Rest Framework , gives error " The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework, file-upload, django-forms, cloudinary

i was able to post the image but don't know why i am not able to update the image , i am using default form provided by DRF
i did not find any solutions yet for this one
i am uploading image via cloudinary api

**the error**

```
{
    "image_1": [
        "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."
    ],
    "image_2": [
        "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."
    ]
}
```

**Model:**

```py
class MyDetail(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    image_1=models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    image_2=models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**Views:**

```py
class SingleDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset=MyDetail.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SingleDetailSerializer
    lookup_field='id'

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()

        image_1 = request.FILES.get('image_1',None)
        image_2 = request.FILES.get('image_2',None)
        if image_1:
            uploaded_image_1 = cloudinary.uploader.upload(image_1)
            request.data['image_1'] = uploaded_image_1['secure_url']
        if image_2:
            uploaded_image_2 = cloudinary.uploader.upload(image_2)
            request.data['image_2'] = uploaded_image_2['secure_url']
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)
        return Response({"message": "Updated successfully.", "data": serializer.data})

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
```

**serializer:**

```py
class SingleDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_1 = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None,use_url=True,required=False)
    image_2 = serializers.ImageField (max_length=None,use_url=True,required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = MyDetail
        fields = ['id','name','image_1','image_2']
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        representation['image_1'] = instance.image_1
        representation['image_2'] = instance.image_2
        return representation
```

my DRF Form image
[image: error image on DRF form]

i even tried from my react form but it was still not working , i was not able to find solutions online and i don't know why it is not able to recognize the file though i uploaded the file. Help me to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i solved it

Instead of updating image through ***views*** , i updated image directly ***serializer***  where i modified the url field to image field to upload the image

**views :**

```py
class SingleDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset=MyDetail.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SingleDetailSerializer
    lookup_field='id'
```

**serializer :**

```py
class SingleDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_1 = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True, required=False)
    image_2 = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = MyDetail
        fields = ['id','name','image_1','image_2']
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        representation['image_1'] = instance.image_1
        representation['image_2'] = instance.image_2
        return representation

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        image_1 = validated_data.get('image_1',None)
        image_2 = validated_data.get('image_2',None)
        if image_1:
            uploaded_image_1 = cloudinary.uploader.upload(image_1)
            validated_data['image_1'] = uploaded_image_1['secure_url']
        if image_2:
            uploaded_image_2 = cloudinary.uploader.upload(image_2)
            validated_data['image_2'] = uploaded_image_2['secure_url']
        instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
        return instance
```